# MapStoreFactory for multiple maps in Hazelcast

Tags: caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have multiple maps that I need to initialize in Hazelcast. From what I have understood so far, implementing `MapStoreFactory` can help me do it. So I implement a `MapStoreFactory` interface which takes `mapName` as parameter and instantiates a `GenericMapStore`. My question is-

1) Will the `GenericMapStore` have `if-else` blocks to initialize different maps.

2) When using wildcards for config files I am doing something like

```
Config config = new Config();  
MapConfig mcf1 = config.getMapConfig("*");
mscf1.setClassName("com.t.g.x.server.hazelcast.MapStoreImpl.*";
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
IMap<String, User> userDetailsMap = hz.getMap("userDetailsMap");
```

how will config know the name of the `MapStoreImplementation` and what change do I need to make to this for `MapStoreFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is meant by GenericMapStore but MapStoreFactory is quite straightforward:

```
mapStoreConfig.setFactoryImplementation( new MapStoreFactory<Object, Object>() {
  @Override
  public MapLoader<Object, Object> newMapStore( String mapName, Properties properties ) {
    return YOUR_MAPLOADER_IMPL;
  }
});
```

So whatever impl you provide here, will be for mapName i.e. the map that you create in your app.

Comment: is `YOUR_MAPLOADER_IMPL` here the mapstore implementation

Comment: right now what I am doing looks something like  `YOUR_MAPLOADER_IMPL` is the `GenericMapStore` and `GenericMapStore` contains a constructor(parameter is `mapName`) which initializes the mapName field in `GenericMapStore` and then the methods `load`, `loadAll`  etc. contains `if-else` for initializing different maps depending upon the `mapName`

Comment: Yes. YOUR_MAPLOADER_IMPL is your MapStore implementation.

Comment: [code example](https://gist.github.com/gurbuzali/5843beacd599f11b3625) is what I am doing now will the different methods have `if-else` blocks for handling different mapNames

Comment: I’m not sure what you are after. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I want to do something like this [https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3783](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3783) once I pass the mapName through the MapStoreFactory do I need if-else blocks inside the various methods to handle different mapnames